# Best practices for controlling flow data when moving to different activities flow and coming back

Tags: android, software-design

I have this situation where the user moves from the home page(it has many sections: gaming, cooking, technology, etc).  When moving from home page activity to gaming, I am passing account information to gaming activity. From gaming activity then I have a flowdata(using singleton I am saving temporary data into a class) where I save information necessary to go to navigate to different game types such as action. Once I am in action section I retrieve data from previous flowdata and move to another activity where I can select the specific game.  Finally I go to the pay activity and then have to come back to my section "gaming" not the homepage.

My problem is when navigating back to gaming activity the account information(which home page passed it to gaming activity) is gone(null) as activity called onDestroy().

My solution is to have a class SectionFlowControl, this class will have an object flowdata which will save at first the account data passed from homepage to this activity.  As I move to different sections I will save the information needed to move to the selected sections such as gaming.  Once I am done with gaming flow(paid the game) I will clear sensitive information and go to SectionFlowControl which will then take me to the respective section such as gaming, technology, everything saved through the section will be cleared but the account information and data needed to send to the sections.

Is this the right approach or is there something better? What would be the best practices to move temporary data when we have many flows?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a large amount of data I would store the relevant information using SharedPreferences.

I would store them on the Home Page and retrieve them in all the other Activities. This way you avoid the need to send and re-send the same info across them